# Laravel dusk authenticate custom user model

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-dusk

i'm trying to create a Page that extends "DuskTestCase" to avoid having to write login logic in every tests. However, when I run the tests, it fails to assert that after a login, the browser is at the home page. Here is one of the things that I tried. Note that Auth::check() returns false, and the problem surely comes from here and I can't figure why it does not authenticate the user as described in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/dusk
The ICOUser model also is implementing Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable contract.

**LoginPage.php**

```
namespace Tests\Browser\Pages;

use ARM\Tcollect\ICO\ICOUser;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginPage extends Page
{
const SUDOER_ID = 499;
/**
* Get the URL for the page.
*
* @return string
*/
public function url()
{
    return '/';
}

/**
* Abstract the Login functionality
*
* @param  \Laravel\Dusk\Browser  $browser
* @param  string  $name
* @return void
*/
public function loginSudoer(Browser $browser)
{
    $browser->loginAs(ICOUser::find(static::SUDOER_ID))- >visit('/home');
}
}
```

The failing method on my **LoginTest.php** is the following:

```
public function testLoginSudoer()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser){
           $browser->on(new LoginPage)
                   ->loginSudoer()
                   ->waitForLocation('/home', 10)
                   ->assertPathIs('/home')
                   ->visit('/logout');
       });
    }
```

**EDIT**: I have also tried without for which Auth::check() returns true, but it doesn't pass either.

```
public function testLoginSudoer()
{
    Auth::loginUsingId(499);
    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser){
       $browser->visit('/home')
               ->waitForLocation('/home', 20)
               ->assertPathIs('/home')
               ->visit('/logout');
   });
}
```

Also, when manually navigating with real google chrome to `/_dusk/login/499` and then `/home`, it works. If I do the same thing with dusk, it doesn't go to /home.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `->loginSudoer($browser)`?

Comment: In the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/dusk#pages), they use it that way. I also tried passing browser in loginSudoer, but it did not work either.

Comment: Can you try `$browser->loginAs(ICOUser::find(static::SUDOER_ID))->visit('/home')->assertPathIs('/home');`?

Comment: I get an error saying "Actual path [/] does not equal expected path [/home]."

Comment: Is there any redirection from `/home` to `/`?

Comment: Only if a user is not authenticated, yes it will be redirected to /

Comment: Did you add your custom `ICOUser` to the list of providers in the config of Laravel?

Comment: I have the followign array in config/auth.php
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => ARM\Tcollect\ICO\ICOUser::class,
        ],
    ],

Comment: The best way to know if it's authenticated or not, you can try `$browser->loginAs(...)->assertAuthenticated();` to see if the problem comes from authentication or somewhere else.